# Convex optimization problem with nuclear norm constraint

Tags: optimization, convex, constrained-optimization

We have the following convex optimization problem:$$
\text{minimize} \quad f({\bf X}) \quad \text{with constraint} \quad \|{\bf X}\|_{\rm tr} \leq t
$$

Where $\|{\bf X}\|_{\rm tr}$ is the Schatten 1-norm/nuclear norm. Say we proceed using the **Frank-Wolfe** algorithm. What do the Frank-Wolfe iterates look like?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community it is indeed a specific problem.